# How to get the result inside callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

If I want to write the result inside callback function to response, but I can't access the res variable in the function, and also I can't access the result outside the function.

So how to pass value between inside and outside?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer
(
    function (req, res)
    {
        var output='';
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});


        //The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        var options = {
          host: 'www.random.org',
          path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        };

        callback = function(response) {
          var str = '';

          //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
          response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
          });

          //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
          response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str);

            //output+=str; //get result
          });
        }

        http.request(options, callback).end();


        //output+=str; //get result
        res.end(output);
    }
).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

---

ver2

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer
(
    function (req, res)
    {
        var output='';
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});


        //The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        var options = {
          host: 'www.random.org',
          path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        };

        callback = function(response) {
          var str = '';

          //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
          response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
          });

          //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
          response.on('end', function () {
            res.write('inside');
          });
        }

        http.request(options, callback).end();

        res.write('outside');
        res.end(output);
    }
).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

---

ver3

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer
(
    function (req, res)
    {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});


        //The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        var options = {
          host: 'www.random.org',
          path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        };

        callback = function(res) {
          var str = '';

          //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
          res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
          });

          //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
          res.on('end', function () {
            res.write('inside');
            //or
            this.write('inside');
          });
        }

        http.request(options, callback).end();


        res.write('outside');
        res.end();
    }
).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

---

ver4

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer
(
    function (req, res)
    {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});


        //The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        var options = {
          host: 'www.random.org',
          path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
        };

        callback = function(response) {
          var str = '';

          //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
          response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
          });

          //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
          response.on('end', function () {
            res.write('inside');
          });
        }

        http.request(options, callback);


        res.write('outside');
        res.end();
    }
).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: I' sorry for non-constructive comment, but how come it is possible to listen on ports in javascript? Does the `node.js` use some hidden java applets to achieve that?

Comment: @TomášZato: Node is running on server side

Comment: Ah, wow. So this is not executed by browsers at all. Servers in Javascript? What happens next? OS in javascript...? Thank you anyway.

Comment: @TomášZato: Hehe, it is really cool indeed! You should check it out: http://nodejs.org/

Comment: @TomášZato: Fabrice Bellard's [jslinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) boots linux on your javascript VM. In the browser. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The function that sets up the callback will have finished and returned before the callback executes. If it didn't, then the callback wouldn't be needed.

Do whatever work you need to do in the callback itself, not in the parent function.

> I can't access the res variable in the function

You should be able to. It is still in scope.

(Although if you call `end()` on it before the callback runs, then breakage should be expected).

Comment: In ver2, I added res.write('inside') and res.write('outside'), and the output is just "outside", this test shows that the res is out of scope, only the parent function can output to response, if not in parent function, I don't know how to do.

Comment: @CLSo — Read the last line of the answer again.

Comment: … and tested version 2 with change implied by that line and it works.

Comment: I still cannot solve the problem, I tried to change the response to res (ver3), then it terminate with error (TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'write'), res.write and this.write are same, that means two objects are different. And I also read the last line of answer, and tried to remove the .end() (ver4), this time is no error, but the output still is only "outside". I don't understand why you can access the res object which is the outside of callback function, maybe this is version problem? my version is 0.8.20

Comment: `res` is defined in the scope of the anonymous function that gets passed to `createServer`. The callback function is defined inside that anonymous function. Anything in scope for the anonymous function is therefore also in scope for the callback function unless the callback function defines a variable with the same name in its scope (and thus masks the one from the outside scope).

Comment: You are outputting `inside` when the `end` event is received. **Move** the call to `end` so it occurs at the end of the call back, **don't re**-move it.